# how do i __add__ between superclass and subclass?

Tags: python

i have a def in super class

```
def __add__(self, other):
    sumAn = self.n[0]+other.n[0]
    colors = ["yellow", "blue", "red"]
    res=colors
    if self.c==other.c:
        sumAc=self.c
    else:
        for i in range(len(colors)):
            if self.c in colors:
                res.remove(self.c)
            elif  other.c in colors:
                res.remove(other.c)
        sumAc=res[0]

        return ALIEN(sumAn, sumAc)
```

and i want to make this conditions for inherit and add more condition like

```
sumLord="LORD"
return SuperAlien(sumAn, sumAc,sumLord)
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the super method

```
def __add__(self, other):
    alien = super().__add__(other)
    sumLord = "LORD"
    return SuperAlien(alien.sumAn, alien.sumAc, sumLord)
```